# Use Android AccountManager to do AppEngine login through UserService

Tags: android, google-app-engine, oauth

I'm using Google AppEngine, and I'm using their [UserService](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingusers) class to handle user accounts and logging in. I don't need to access any information about their account - I'm just using it to differentiate users.

Now the website is mostly just a backend. I'm using an Android app for the frontend. I know you can access Google user accounts on the device using the [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/authenticate.html). It's definitely the safest way to get a user to log in. And I got that much to work.

Where I'm stuck is passing the login information from the Android app to the AppEngine website. From what I've ready I should be using OAuth, and I see the walkthrough [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/oauth-and-tasks-on-android) for using it with Google APIs, but I don't need to access an API, just to log in. I've been able to acquire an Authentication Token in the app, but I'm not sure how to pass it to the website, or if that's even the right direction. Should I be using a specific OAuth login on the server, like [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400428/can-i-use-androids-accountmanager-for-getting-oauth-access-token-for-appengine)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's the relevant code:

Server (GAE):

```
UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
User user = userService.getCurrentUser();

if (user == null) {
    resp.sendRedirect(userService.createLoginURL(req.getRequestURI()));
    return;
}
```

Client (Android):

```
AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this);
Account[] accounts = am.getAccountsByType("com.google");

Bundle options = new Bundle();

am.getAuthToken(
        accounts[0],                     // Account retrieved using getAccountsByType()
        "Manage your tasks",            // Auth scope
        options,                        // Authenticator-specific options
        this,                           // Your activity
        new OnTokenAcquired(),          // Callback called when a token is successfully acquired
        new Handler(new OnError()));
//Now what!?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [blog post](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/05/Authenticating-against-App-Engine-from-an-Android-app) covered exactly what I needed.

For two alternate (and in my opinion less than ideal) solutions, check out this thread: [Webservice credentials - OpenID/Android AccountManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352592/webservice-credentials-openid-android-accountmanager)